# SSRS - Column Chart with multiple Categories

Tags: charts, reporting-services

I want to use SQL Report Builder to create a column chart based on this data:

[image]

The diagram should look like in the picture and can be easily generated with Excel.
But how do I create the chart with SQL Report Builder?

[image]

I can manage with one department with these settings:

[image]

Current result for one department:

[image]

Excel was used for illustration purposes only. The data comes from a MS SQL Server 2016 with SSRS installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be much easier if you normalise your data. How you do that is up to you but based on your sample data, I just used an `UNPIVOT` to get the data into a sensible format.

Here's the dataset query I used to reproduce and unpivot your sample data

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Costs varchar(20), Dev float, Sales float, AfterSales float)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Actual', 23347.48, 66691.95, 8981.62),
('Expected', 20000, 30000, 70000),
('Target', 5000, 15000, 5000)

SELECT * FROM @t
unpivot 
(
    Amount FOR Dept IN (Dev, Sales, AfterSales)
) as up
```

This gives us the following output

[image]

Now all we need to do is setup the chart as follows...

[image]

And the result looks like this...

[image]